# Parse String (yyyymmm) Format to DateTime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui, datepicker

I have a field called Accounting Period as char,  `[AccountingPeriod] [char](6)`, how can I parse it to DateTime Format using DatePicker?

I used this KendoGrid for DatePicker

```
@(
    Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
        .Name(nameof(InvoiceDTO.AccountingPeriod))
        .Format("{0:yyyyMM}")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:50%" })
)
```

I have the date: `199805`

Comment: Please give an example of what you get and what you expect as a result

Comment: @Barns I added example: I have the date: 199805

Comment: Please try to be consistent. The title shows format "yyyymmm" your code shows "MMyyyy" but your date example is 199805 which would be year = 9805 and month = 19 according to code.

Comment: @Barns Sorry about that, I fix it

Comment: So "199805" is the input. What is the expected output?

Comment: @Barns "199805" this is how i wanted look in the database and that what i have right now its fine  my problem date-picker doesn't like the date being string and in UI i want to use datepicker thats why i wanted to parse to make date-picker happy but when it save i want to save the string. Hope that clear

Answer (score 1):

Okay, as from the comments I have understood that you have a date in "yyyyMM" format and from that you want the magical line of code to produce you an Object of type `DateTime`. You can do it using this line of code:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("199805", "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var theDate);
```

Feel free to modify it according to your needs.

**UPDATE:**

Regarding your assignment of the date to the `Kendo` datepicker, I would suggest you to create a method and call it inside of the `Value()` method. Something similar to this:

```
@functions{ 
    public DateTime GetDate(string strDate)
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var theDate))
        {
            return theDate;
        }
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

And then you can just call it inside the `Value()` method something like below:

```
@(
    Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
    .Name(nameof(InvoiceDTO.AccountingPeriod))
    .Value(GetDate(InvoiceDTO.AccountingPeriod)) // I assume AccountPeriod is of type string.
    // .Format("{0:yyyyMM}") I do not think we are going to need this after the date is parsed into the required type.
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:50%" })
)
```

*PS:* I have not tested the code, just fire in the air after going through this [article](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datepicker). So, It might need some Love.

Comment: Thanks, How can i Loaded to the date picker? ` @(
            Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
            .Name(nameof(InvoiceDTO.AccountingPeriod))
            .Format("{0:yyyyMM}")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:50%" })
        )`

Comment: Well, you have the date in `DateTime` object type, why don't you just feed it to the Value method? See: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datepicker