# How can i parse kendo date-picker date to MMMyyyy string Format?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I used Kendo Date Picker to Accounting Month Filed this field is a text field, I want to use DatePicker to pick the Month and a year and Display as `052020' as a text

But When i select data it display date as `Tue Jun 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)` how how can i get a month and a date.

in my Grid i have this

```
 new GridColumnSettings
        {
            Member = nameof(Sales.AcountingMonth),
            MemberType = typeof(string),
            Title = "Acounting Month",          
        },
```

and In My popup

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
            .Name(nameof(Sales.AcountingMonth))          
            .Format("MMMyyyy")
            .Value(nameof(Sales.AcountingMonth))           
            )
```

Comment: What format is your `AcountingMonth` property, is it `C#` `DateTime`  object?

Comment: Hi @JamshaidKamran Sorry for the late reply Its is `char(6)`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need a way to get `MMYYYY` formatted string out of your c# `DateTime` object. Well, you can do that, if you go through the `DateTime.ToString()` method, you can feed it the format you want and it will produce the resulting string. In your case it would be something like this:

```
@(
    Html.Kendo()
        .DatePicker()
        .Name(nameof(Sales.AcountingMonth))          
        .Format("MMMyyyy")
        .Value(Sales.AcountingMonth.ToString("MMMyyyy")) 
        // I assume AccountingMonth is of type DateTime.
        // Notice, I removed the nameof call that you were making,
        // which eventually was returning the name of the property that you were referencing.
)
```

**PS:** I just remembered that I had answered a similar question that "YOU" had asked a few days back, which was quite similar to this one. Check [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61298388/4308286)

Comment: I get "An Object reference is for non static field `        .Value(Sales.AcountingMonth.ToString("MMMyyyy")) ` in this line

Comment: I also tried  it as .Value(nameof(Sales.AcountingMonth)).ToString("MMMyyyy")) i get cannot convert `string to IFormatProvider?`

Comment: Jamshaid, Thank you for the help as always  i think the problem is the grid the popup works fine but as soon as i select a data using the datepicker in grid popup the grid column value changes to `Tue Jun 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)`